# Enter isolation mode for selenium element using cdp

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

Currently, I have a code that uses remote selenium server to look for ads and save their images, or take screenshots in case their image isn't easily available. As of now I use:

```
iframes = list(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe'))
```

to obtain each iframe and then loop through them doing `iframe.screenshot(filename)`. This works fine for the most part, but some pages take bad screenshots (they screenshot other aprts of the page or sometimes they have an element blocking the ad).

So what I'm trying to do is use the newly implemented chrome dev tools protocol on selenium to isolate each element, so it's the only visible element on the screen. This should be possible since I'm able enter chrome's dev tools, right click my desired element and "enter isolation mode". I just don't know where to begin with the code because the documentation is pretty messy and no one seems to have posted about this previously.

I've found these methods: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay/#method-setShowIsolatedElements

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-createIsolatedWorld

but I'm not sure how to even test them.

If anyone's got any experience working wiht this or can think of a better solution, I'd greatly apreciate your help.